# Command line SVN help to check the working copy is an outdated copy of the one present in the server

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Hello
I want to implement the following flow in my application.(as shown in the pseudocode)

LatestRevision = IsMyFileLatest();  // some method which should check the svn and compare  the working copy of the file.

```
if (! LatestRevision)  //this flag compares with the Head Revision
{
   //Display error message..The file is not the latest copy
}
else
{
  // Commit the file changes in the subversion server
  FileCommit();   //commits the file(whichever file im working to the server)     
}
```

For this i need help of the following svn commands executed in the command line.

1. to check whether the current file is the latest file ?
2. committing only those files which are modified..in a directory.

Any help or pointers regarding the subversion command line is deeply appreciated.

Thanks and Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by "latest version"? Commit where? In what context? Needs more detail

Comment: Surely subversion does all that for you? That's really its modus operandi.

Comment: the flag Latest version means the "latest revision"...Im sorry im gonna edit this part again,. Regarding commit, its just committing back to the repository, this part im aware

Answer (score 1):

The VisualSVN site hosts a 'book' on Subversion, located [here](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/), which should give you a good starting point - though off the top of my head I'm not sure of the exact commands you'd need to use...

There is a chapter which is a reference for commands:

[SVN Reference](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/).

Explained there is [svn info](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/info/) which may help you out well enough.

EDIT:

On the other hand, after reading your altered title, [svn status](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/status/) may be what you're looking for?

EDIT 2:

Ok, given that the programming language used in your question is not explicitly stated, and the fact it's such a common syntax that we could liken the guesswork to that of beating a dead horse, here's a little snippet in the universal (in the Windows world) VBScript...

```
Dim shell, svn
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set svn = shell.Exec("svn info [working_copy_path]")

WScript.Sleep 1000

Dim revision
Do While svn.StdOut.AtEndOfStream <> True 
    revision = svn.StdOut.ReadLine
    If left(revision, 8) = "Revision" Then
        Exit Do
End If
Loop

WScript.Echo revision
```

I'm far from proud of the `Sleep` mechanism utilised, but luckily I'm not the one with (much of) a responsibility here, so I'll leave generating a clean-cut approach to yourself and just put this out there as an example.

Comment: No svn status would just return me a list of files which are modified. I need something (even if its a 2 step approach), to check my working copy is modified and to check whether its a old revision on which my modifications are made. SVN throws a conflict be default, i was just wondering to handle this scenario in my application level

Comment: Hi ... actually "svn info" looks useful to me, any idea how can i extract "Revision" column info from the result

Comment: @this-Me: how can we advise on how to extract strings if we don't even know in which language or environment you are working?

Comment: @this-Me: Wim is correct, however I'll give it a shot, if I can update my answer after all this time.

Comment: Thanks ... i tried an alternative approach of flushing the contents to an xml file and reading it later using svn info.......Sample svn info C:\Projects\Foo.xml --xml > C:\Projects\FileInfo.xml